# Processing source data to produce chartable summary with MySQL

Tags: mysql

This is a MySql problem.

I'm analysing the amount of time that people spend in a zone.

The raw data is as follows:

```
visit_id person_id zone_id  timeIn    timeOut
1           1         1     10:58:10  11:03:07
2           1         1     11:03:59  11:04:10
3           2         1     10:52:10  10:53:59
4           2         1     10:57:03  10:57:22
5           2         1     10:57:55  10:58:27
6           2         2     11:04:33  11:05:17
```

(I added the MySQL data definition at the end)

The output is a bar chart like this:
Sorry. Just found out I can't include the image. It is a minute by minute bar chart showing the count of people in that zone. Importantly, if there is no one in the zone for that minute, it shows a zero entry. If that requirement is not there then the problem is much more straightforward.

The input to the Bar Chart Module needs to look like this (notice the zero elements that are required):

```
zone_id  hourMinute count
1        10:52:00   1
1        10:53:00   1
1        10:54:00   0
1        10:55:00   0
1        10:56:00   0
1        10:57:00   1
1        10:58:00   2
1        10:59:00   1
1        11:00:00   1
1        11:01:00   1
1        11:02:00   1
1        11:03:00   1
1        11:04:00   1
2        10:52:00   0
2        10:53:00   0
2        10:54:00   0
2        10:55:00   0
2        10:56:00   0
2        10:57:00   0
2        10:58:00   0
2        10:59:00   0
2        11:00:00   0
2        11:01:00   0
2        11:02:00   0
2        11:03:00   0
2        11:04:00   1
2        11:05:00   1
```

Also, the raw data above is for two bar charts (zone 1 and zone 2). I have only shown the chart for zone 1.

I am able to create the data in a number of stages by transferring data back and forth between the database and the back end scripts but it is cumbersome, difficult to support and inefficient.

I suspect that it must be possible to do it all in mysql but I'm not competent enough to get there myself.

Can anyone show the mysql that is needed to get from the input to the required output?

Thanks!

---

### Appendix:

If it helps to understand the problem, the intermediate structures I create in database and the back end are as follows:

**Process 1: break out**

```
visit_id    person_id zone_id hourMinute
1           1         1       10:58:00
1           1         1       10:59:00
1           1         1       11:00:00
1           1         1       11:01:00
1           1         1       11:02:00
1           1         1       11:03:00
2           1         1       11:03:00
2           1         1       11:04:00
3           2         1       10:52:00
3           2         1       10:53:00
4           2         1       10:57:00
5           2         1       10:57:00
5           2         1       10:58:00
6           2         2       11:04:00
6           2         2       11:05:00
```

**Process 02: Sort by hourMinute**

```
visit_id    person_id zone_id hourMinute
3           2         1       10:52:00
3           2         1       10:53:00
4           2         1       10:57:00
5           2         1       10:57:00
1           1         1       10:58:00
5           2         1       10:58:00
1           1         1       10:59:00
1           1         1       11:00:00
1           1         1       11:01:00
1           1         1       11:02:00
1           1         1       11:03:00
2           1         1       11:03:00
2           1         1       11:04:00
6           2         2       11:04:00
6           2         2       11:05:00
```

**Process 03: Count**

```
zone_id     hourMinute  count   
1           10:52:00    1   
1           10:53:00    1   
1           10:57:00    1   
1           10:58:00    2   
1           10:59:00    1   
1           11:00:00    1   
1           11:01:00    1   
1           11:02:00    1   
1           11:03:00    1   person_id 1 visited twice in same minute
1           11:04:00    1   
2           11:04:00    1   
2           11:05:00    1
```

**Data Definition for Input**

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `test` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `test`;
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.6.11, for Win32 (x86)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.14

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `tb_stackoverflowquestion01`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tb_stackoverflowquestion01`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `tb_stackoverflowquestion01` (
  `visit_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeIn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeOut` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`visit_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Question asked here:\nhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723032/processing-source-data-to-produce-chartable-summary-with-mysql';
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tb_stackoverflowquestion01`
--

LOCK TABLES `tb_stackoverflowquestion01` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tb_stackoverflowquestion01` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `tb_stackoverflowquestion01` VALUES (16,1,1,'2013-01-01 10:58:10','2013-01-01 11:03:07'),(17,1,1,'2013-01-01 11:03:59','2013-01-01 11:04:10'),(18,2,1,'2013-01-01 10:52:10','2013-01-01 10:53:59'),(19,2,1,'2013-01-01 10:57:03','2013-01-01 10:57:22'),(20,2,1,'2013-01-01 10:57:55','2013-01-01 10:58:27'),(21,2,2,'2013-01-01 11:04:33','2013-01-01 11:05:17');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `tb_stackoverflowquestion01` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping routines for database 'test'
--
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2013-11-01  8:36:33
```

From this point, the next step is the final output shown towards the top of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I persevered and created the solution myself:

In short, I created a date table with all possible dates in for the next 50 years (shoot me).

Then created a time table with all possible times in at minute intervals for 24 hours (shoot me again).

Then did a cartesian join to created a list of dates / times within the high and low bounds of the set being considered and left joined that with the raw data when the dateTime was within the limits of that raw record.

Then grouped and counted.

Not sure how speedy it will be in live with hundreds of thousands of records but I suspect better than passing back and forth between DB and back end.

Any tips or hints to improve performance or increase elegance gratefully received :)

SQL is below for zone_id 1:

```
select dateTimeC, count(zone_id)
from 
    (
        SELECT dateTimeC, tb_stackoverflowquestion01.zone_id, person_id 
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT 
                    addTime(date, time) as dateTimeC,
                    zone_id
                FROM tb_date, tb_time, tb_stackoverflowquestion01

                where tb_date.date >= 
                    (
                        select date(min(timeIn))
                        from  tb_stackoverflowquestion01
                        where zone_id = 1 
                    )
                and tb_date.date <= 
                    (
                        select date(max(timeOut))
                        from  tb_stackoverflowquestion01
                        where zone_id = 1 
                    )
                and time >= 
                    (
                        select time(addTime(min(timein),-second(min(timeIn))))
                        from  tb_stackoverflowquestion01
                        where zone_id = 1 
                    )
                and time <= 
                    (
                        select time(max(timeOut))
                        from  tb_stackoverflowquestion01
                        where zone_id = 1 
                    )

                group by dateTimeC
            ) as t1
        left join tb_stackoverflowquestion01
        on  dateTimeC >= addTime(timein, -second((timeIn)))
        and dateTimeC <= timeOut
        and t1.zone_id = tb_stackoverflowquestion01.zone_id

        group by dateTimeC, zone_id, person_id
    ) as t2
group by dateTimeC
```